# How to generate normally distributed random from an integer range?

Tags: c#, random, range, gaussian, normal-distribution

Given the start and the end of an integer range, how do I calculate a normally distributed random integer between this range?

I realize that the normal distribution goes into -+ infinity. I guess the tails can be cutoff, so when a random gets computed outside the range, recompute. This elevates the probability of integers in the range, but as long as the this effect is tolerable (<5%), it's fine.

```
public class Gaussian
{
    private static bool uselast = true;
    private static double next_gaussian = 0.0;
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static double BoxMuller()
    {
        if (uselast) 
        { 
            uselast = false;
            return next_gaussian;
        }
        else
        {
            double v1, v2, s;
            do
            {
                v1 = 2.0 * random.NextDouble() - 1.0;
                v2 = 2.0 * random.NextDouble() - 1.0;
                s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
            } while (s >= 1.0 || s == 0);

            s = System.Math.Sqrt((-2.0 * System.Math.Log(s)) / s);

            next_gaussian = v2 * s;
            uselast = true;
            return v1 * s;
        }
    }

    public static double BoxMuller(double mean, double standard_deviation)
    {
        return mean + BoxMuller() * standard_deviation;
    }

    public static int Next(int min, int max)
    {
        return (int)BoxMuller(min + (max - min) / 2.0, 1.0); 
    }
}
```

I probably need to scale the standard deviation some how relative to the range, but don't understand how.

Answer:

```
    // Will approximitely give a random gaussian integer between min and max so that min and max are at
    // 3.5 deviations from the mean (half-way of min and max).
    public static int Next(int min, int max)
    {
        double deviations = 3.5;
        int r;
        while ((r = (int)BoxMuller(min + (max - min) / 2.0, (max - min) / 2.0 / deviations)) > max || r < min)
        {
        }

        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the Box-Muller method returns a "standard" normal distribution, it will have mean 0 and standard deviation 1.  To transform a standard normal distribution, you multiply your random number by X to get standard deviation X, and you add Y to obtain mean Y, if memory serves me correctly.

See the [Wikipedia article's section on normalizing standard normal variables (property 1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standardizing_normal_random_variables) for a more formal proof.

---

In response to your comment, the rule of thumb is that 99.7% of a normal distribution will be within +/- 3 times the standard deviation.  If you need a normal distribution from 0 to 100 for instance, than your mean will be halfway, and your SD will be (100/2)/3 = 16.667.  So whatever values you get out of your Box-Muller algorithm, multiply by 16.667 to "stretch" the distribution out, then add 50 to "center" it.

---

John, in response to your newest comment, I'm really not sure what is the point of the `Next` function.  It always uses a standard deviation of 1 and a mean of halfway between your min and max.

If you want a mean of Y, with ~99.7% of the numbers in the range -X to +X, then you just call `BoxMuller(Y, X/3)`.

Comment: Yes, this is what the BoxMuller(double mean, double standard_deviation) achieves above. The problem, however, is that the Next(int min, int max) returns values very close to the half way of the range. This is because I don't understand how to "scale" the deviation correctly.

Comment: So for 3.5 standard deviations, it would be "return (int)BoxMuller(min + (max - min) / 2.0, (max - min) / 2.0 / 3.5);"?

Comment: Can I just comment that +/- 3 times standard deviation gives you not 97% but 99.7%.
+/-sigma: ~68%
+/-2sigma: ~95%
+/-3sigma: ~99.7%
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68-95-99.7_rule

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Dmitry -- my statistics were a bit rusty, apparently.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the -2*sigma..+2*sigma will give you 95% of the bell curve.
(check the "Standard deviation and confidence intervals" section in the already mentioned wiki article).

So modify this piece:

```
return (int)BoxMuller(min + (max - min) / 2.0, 1.0);
```

and change 1.0 (standard deviation) to 2.0 (or even more if you want more than 95% coverage)

```
return (int)BoxMuller(min + (max - min) / 2.0, 2.0);
```

Comment: Now I understand what I want to formulate thanks to you.. I want the -2*sigma .. +2*sigma to be at the beginning and the end of the range (min, max) respectively.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. So you want to step out from your mean value left and right and "hit" either min or max with a 95% confidence.
In this case - you keep your mean as you have it (min + (max-min)/2), but you need to calculate your sigma (standard deviation). Stepping out by 2*sigma gives us that 95% interval. So the length of this interval is 4*sigma. But we can also calculate it as (max-min). Which gives us sigma=(max-min)/4.
Can you please try that?

Comment: "hit" within the min..max range with the 95% confidence - just to be precise in my wording.

Comment: This works also, too bad I can only make one answer as correct. Stackoverflow should add "assisted" or "shared" answers.