# triggering an event with a certain probability with C#

Tags: c#, random, simulation, probability

I'm trying to simulate a realistic key press event. For that reason I'm using SendInput() method, but for greater result I need to specify the delay between keyDOWN and KeyUP events! These numbers below show the elapsed time in milliseconds between DOWN and UP events (these are real/valid):

96
95
112
111
119
104
143
96
95
104
120
112
111
88
104
119
111
103
95
104
95
127
112
143
144
142
143
128
144
112
111
112
120
128
111
135
118
147
96
135
103
64
64
87
79
112
88
111
111
112
111
104
87
95

**We can simplify the output:**

delay 64 - 88 ms -> 20% of a time

delay 89 - 135 ms -> 60% of a time

delay 136 - 150 ms -> 20 % of a time

**How do I trigger an event according to probabilities from above?** Here is the code I'm using right now:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
            Random r = new Random();
            int rez = r.Next(0, 5); // 0,1,2,3,4 - five numbers total

            if (rez == 0) // if 20% (1/5)
            {
                Random r2 = new Random();
                textBox2.AppendText(" " + rez + " " + r2.Next(64, 88) + Environment.NewLine);
// do stuff
            }
            else if (rez == 4)//if 20% (1/5)
            {
                Random r3 = new Random();
                textBox2.AppendText(" " + rez + " " + r3.Next(89, 135) + Environment.NewLine);
// do stuff

            }
            else // if 1 or 2 or 3 (3/5) -> 60%
            {
                Random r4 = new Random();
                textBox2.AppendText(" " + rez + " " + r4.Next(136, 150) + Environment.NewLine);
// do stuff

            }

        }
```

There is a huge problem with this code. In theory, after millions of iterations - the resulting graph will look similar to this:

[image: comparison]

How to deal with this problem?

**EDIT:** the solution was to use distribution as people suggested.

here is java implementation of such code:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29

and here is C# implementation:

[How to generate normally distributed random from an integer range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303368/how-to-generate-normally-distributed-random-from-an-integer-range)

although I'd suggest to decrease the value of "deviations" a little.

here is interesting msdn article

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/02/21/generating-random-non-uniform-data-in-c.aspx

everyone thanks for help!

Comment: for a start, you should initialise Random with a seed, or you'll get the same every time

Comment: First of all: don't always instantiate a new `Random`, because the output is dependent on the seed which will be the same for two `Random` objects created at the same time (sequentially). So the next random will be the same.

Comment: in real app i'm initializing Randoms once, on Form load event. This is special "stackoverflow" version of my code..

Comment: @Aidan - that is not completely correct. If you initialise Random without a seed, it uses the clock as the seed. So two instances of Random will only have the same seed if you instantiated them so close together that the clock hadn't changed. If you create two some milliseconds apart, you get different results. [Thread.Sleep(20) seems to do the trick on mine]

Comment: @Rob Levine - thanks for correcting me, I did not know that. Has it always been like that in previous versions of .Net. I always give a seed by default, so I wonder if I once had a good reason for it or whether I have always been deluded

Comment: @Aidan - yes - it has always been like this. Though if you were creating the `Random` instances very close together then you would see the behaviour you describe because the clock used as the seed would not have ticked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to generate a normal distribution. The built-in .NET class generates a [Uniform Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29).

Gaussian or Normal distribution random numbers are possible using the built-in Random class by using the [Box-Muller transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables).

You should end up with a nice probability curve like this

[image: Normal Distribution]

(taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

To transform a Normally Distributed random number into an integer range, the Box-Muller transform can help with this again. See this [previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303406/303612) which describes the process and links to the mathematical proof.

Comment: Given that we are talking about values that can only be positive, a pure Normal distribution is incorrect, because its domain goes from - infinity to + infinity.

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this case because the observed delays are large compared to the variance, but if we were dealing with short delays, a Normal approximation would likely return negative delays.

Comment: If you take a look at this question, it is possible to transform a normal distribution using the Box-Muller transform. This can be used to give a normally distributed random number within a positive integer range: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303368/how-to-generate-normally-distributed-random-from-an-integer-range

Comment: This may be nitpicking, but while the Box-Muller transformation does generate a Normal distribution, my comment about the integer range holds: by definition, if a distribution is bound by a range, it cannot be a Normal distribution. It will be a distribution that is somewhat shaped like a Normal. The algorithm presented simply chops off the results that fall outside of the min, max range: if min and max are for instance -sigma, +sigma in your chart, the algorithm will return results that fall in the dark area, and that is not a Normal.

Comment: I agree with Mathias. It cannot be a normal distribution. If one wants to do this right, I think one should first test/prove the probability distribution. Assuming that the intervals between keystrokes have exponential distribution has much more sense than trying to adjust the shape of normal distribution. Why? It's mentioned in Mathias post.

Answer (score 2):

This is the right idea, I just think you need to use doubles instead of ints so you can partition the probability space between 0 and 1. This will allow you to get a finer grain, as follows :

1. Normalise the real values by dividing all the values by the largest value
2. Divide the values into buckets - the more buckets, the closer the graph will be to the continuous case
3. Now, the larger the bucket the more chance of the event being raised. So, partition the interval [0,1] according to how many elements are in each bucket. So, if you have 20 real values, and a bucket has 5 values in it, it takes up a quarter of the interval.
4. On each test, generate a random number between 0-1 using Random.NextDouble() and whichever bucket the random number falls into, raise an event with that parameter. So for the numbers you provided, here are the values for 5 buckets buckets :

[image]

This is a bit much to put in a code example, but hopefully this gives the right idea

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to model the delays as an [Exponential Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). The exponential distribution models the time between events that occur continuously and independently at a constant average rate - which sounds like a fair assumption given your problem.

You can estimate the parameter lambda by taking the inverse of the average of your real observed delays, and simulate the distribution using [this approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates), i.e.

delay = -Math.Log(random.NextDouble()) / lambda

However, looking at your sample, the data looks too "concentrated" around the mean to be a pure Exponential, so simulating that way would result in delays with the proper mean, but too spread out to match your sample.

One way to address that is to model the process as a shifted Exponential; essentially, the process is shifted by a value which represents the minimum the value can take, instead of 0 for an exponential. In code, taking the shift as the minimum observed value from your sample, this could look like this:

```
var sample = new List<double>()
                  {
                     96,
                     95,
                     112,
                     111,
                     119,
                     104,
                     143,
                     96,
                     95,
                     104,
                     120,
                     112
                  };

var min = sample.Min();
sample = sample.Select(it => it - min).ToList();

var lambda = 1d / sample.Average();

var random = new Random();
var result = new List<double>();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   var simulated = min - Math.Log(random.NextDouble()) / lambda;
   result.Add(simulated);
   Console.WriteLine(simulated);
}
```

A trivial alternative, which is in essence similar to Aidan's approach, is to re-sample: pick random elements from your original sample, and the result will have exactly the desired distribution:

```
var sample = new List<double>()
                  {
                     96,
                     95,
                     112,
                     111,
                     119,
                     104,
                     143,
                     96,
                     95,
                     104,
                     120,
                     112
                  };

var random = new Random();
var size = sample.Count();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(sample[random.Next(0, size)]);
}
```