# Generate random number between 0 and 1 with (negative)exponential distribution

Tags: java, random, probability

Heyho,

I'm trying to generate a random number between 0.0 and 1.0 with exponential/negative exponential distribution. There is an [article](http://ericlippert.com/2012/02/21/generating-random-non-uniform-data/), which tells that you have to get the **"quantile function"**. But the results are still greater than 1.0. So I would need to scale my equation somehow.

My goal is to generate a random number in a range, where for example higher/lower values have a higher probability. (The distribution should be scalable)

**Related questions(don't truncate the result to [0,1]):**

- [Pseudorandom Number Generator - Exponential Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution)
- [Generate random number between 0 and 1 with guassian distributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973043/generate-random-number-between-0-and-1-with-guassian-distributes)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates

Comment: (Of course, an exponential distribution has an infinite tail, so you'll have to approximate...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth is there maybe an other distribution (with [0,1]) which behaves like an exponential, the higher the x, the higher the probability of a higher y or the higher the x, the lower the probability of a higher y?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The negative exponential distribution has support on the range [0, ∞), so I'm interpreting your question as a request for a truncated negative exponential. The Cumulative Distribution Function for such a beast with lower limit `l >= 0`, upper limit `h > l`, and rate `λ` is

```
F(x) = (exp(-λl) - exp(-λx)) / (exp(-λl) - exp(-λh))
```

We can find the inversion by setting this equal to `U`, a uniform(0,1) random number, and solving for `x`:

```
X = -ln(exp(-λl) - (exp(-λl) - exp(-λh)) * U) / λ
```

Since you specified lower and upper limits of 0 and 1, respectively, this reduces to

```
X = -ln(1 - (1 - exp(-λ)) * U) / λ
```

Replace `U` with a call to your favorite U(0,1) generator and that's your algorithm for generating `X`'s with the desired distribution.

Here's a histogram of 10,000 values generated with `λ = 5`.  Smaller values of `λ` give a flatter distribution, larger values show a more rapid exponential drop off.

[image: 10,000 truncated exponentials with lambda = 5]

Comment: Thanks man :D I think the hardest task was to get what I wanted :D (also because I wasn't sure either), but this is exactly what I was looking for! (You can also test it over here: http://www.petrileskinen.fi/random/randomDistribution.html) Which tool did you use to generate the histogram?

Comment: I use JMP for a lot of my statistical analyses.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment that you want both lower and higher numbers to have a higher likelihood:

```
// let u,v be random real numbers from [1, 10]
x = log(u) // x is from 0.0 to 1.0, with higher probability getting higher values.
y = 1 - log(v) // y is from 0.0 to 1.0, with higher probability of getting lower values.
if abs(x - 0.5) > abs(y - 0.5):
    return x
else:
    return y
```

This is a bit hacky, but it makes it extremely unlikely to get a value exactly in the middle `0.5` and likely to get the edge values.  It seems to fit your requirements though.

EDIT: It could use some fine tuning when `x == y`.  You could use another random choice to determine which to select in that case:

```
if x == y:
    // let w be a random number either 1 or 2.
    if w == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return y
```

Additionally, if the application calls for this function to be a bit more or less polar, it can be adapted to do so:

```
// let u,v be random real numbers from [1, K] where K > 1 
// and let j be a real number given by log(K).  j is selected by the function's caller.
x = log(u) / j
y = (1 - log(v)) / j
// The remainder of the formula is identical.
```

By using a value like 2 for j, K = 100 and thus is more likely to be a polar value.  If a value less than 10 is used for j, it will be less likely to be a polar value.  In this way you can control the "slope" of the function.

Comment: possible, but not very flexible :P, the random generator is for a game, so it should be quite scalable

Comment: In what way do you want it to "flex"?  I'll bet I could make it work -- just let me know.

Comment: So basicall I want to have a function where I can modify different constants like the slope. By scaling this slope, the probability of higher/lower results changes

Comment: I have modified this answer such that you could have a function provide a constant to determine how polar to make this function.  A value of j > 1 will make it more polar.  A value of j < 1 will make it less polar.

Comment: k, I first need to think about this :D I'll come then back to you :D

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `Math.random()` to generate a random double between 0.0 and 1.0, and then simply take the square root of the result. That would achieve the desired effect ("My goal is to generate a random number in a range, where for example higher values have a higher probability.)

Or is that not what you want, because it's not specifically exponential distribution, but I guess polynomial with degree two?

Comment: This would work, I also already tried it, the problem is only that I also want that lower values can have a higher probability

Comment: I tried this with the equation f(x) = -x² + 1, but somehow the test results didn't really match. It was more linar than exponential

Comment: Do you want the lower values to have a high probability - because your question states the opposite.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to do both. It should be also flexible, so it's much more probable to get a higher result

Comment: would it be possible to scale the output if you take the square root of Math.random()? So the distribution changes and higher values have a much higher probability than before.